# Some help on using index where an object appears multiple times in an array (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am learning how to use the .index function to show a string's position inside an array.  It is pretty useful.  However, I am wondering how I can use it (or some other method) to show ALL the places a string exists in an array?

So for example if I have the code:

```
array= ['cat', 'dog', 'eagle', 'moose', 'pets', 'animal', 'eagle', 'hawk']
puts 'At position ' + array.index('eagle').to_s + ' in the array is eagle!'
puts array.index('eagle')
```

each time, it tells me that the position is 2, even though it is 2 and also position 6 in the array.  Is there a simple way to get back all the instances of a particular string within an array?  Or would I need to write a loop to do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
array.each_index.select { |i| array[i] == value } #=> [2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get the array elements into pairs of `[obj, index]` using `each_with_index`, then select pairs where `obj` is `'eagle'`, and finally return all the `index` values (last in a pair, so use the `last` method):

```
array.each_with_index.select { |x| x[0] == 'eagle' }.map(&:last)
# => [2, 6]
```

As a convenience method in `Array`:

```
class Array
  def indices_of(obj)
    each_with_index.select { |x| x[0] == obj }.map(&:last)
  end
end

['cat', 'dog', 'eagle', 'moose', 'pets', 'animal', 'eagle', 'hawk'].indices_of 'eagle'
# => [2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
value = "eagle"
array.each_with_index { |item, index| puts index if item == value }
```

In your question you just seemed to want to print the index value.  you can do what ever you want in this block.

```
value = "eagle"
array.each_with_index do |item, index| 
  if item == value
    # do whatever you like
    puts index
  end
end
```